# Exceptions using htmlagilitypack

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

i am working with html-agility-pack in vb.net and facing a problem. my project was working fine 2 days ago, but now it is generating some kind of exceptions . i am wondering that what is happening . can anyone please help. screen shots are attached thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why, oh why are you posting screenshots instead of the text of the messages?

Comment: Have you validated that the value of URL_val is a valid URL when that web.Load call is made?

Comment: yes sir i have validated the url. there is no any problem in url.

Comment: Mr. Ided. . . sorry i am new to vb. i could not get the actual error message. i am so confused so i posted the screen shots.

Comment: i also have tested the following sample code but also getting the same exception. . .

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument
    Dim a As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument
    Dim web As HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb
    Private _loadURL As HtmlDocument

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        doc = web.Load("http://Dawn.com/")
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: 1) `http://dawn.com` not `dawn.com`  2) if that's not the problem, the message "unable to connect to server" could mean any number of things such as - the server host realizes you're scraping and has blocked you. If it's not just the lack of a protocol on your url then it's a non-trivial problem

Comment: try other website for example `http://google.com` and tell us the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the problem. thanks everyone for valueable commenting. the proble was due to proxy settings in my default browser. code is totally right.